# Como Puedo mantener un envio constante de datos a una URL en Python

Tags: python, arduino, url

Buenas tardes amigos, estoy un tanto desesperado con un error que obtengo al momento de enviar datos capturados por un arduino, los cuales los envio por el puerto COM a una Raspberry y dentro de esta ejecuto el codigo en python para capturar los datos(estos datos son concatenados), separarlos, asignarles un nombre y posteriormente enviarlos via URL a una IP objetivo para procesar la informacion.

Este es el codigo que ejecuto

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Importamos la libreira de PySerial

import requests
import serial
import time


ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
Sensor1 = "1"
Sensor2 = "2"
Sensor3 = "3"
Sensor4 = "4"
while 1:

    string = str(ser.readline().decode().strip('\r\n'))
    produccion,vivienda = string.split('*')

    url="http://10.100.64.54/insert/"+Sensor1+"/"+produccion   
    url2="http://10.100.64.54/insert/"+Sensor2+"/"+vivienda 

    response=request.get(url) # response 200 = envio satisfactorio
    print(response)  
    response2=request.get(url2) # response 200 = envio satisfactorio
    print(response2)
```

al momento de ejecutarlo, se mantiene un rato estable, me envía los datos que obtengo, puedo procesarlos y todo, pero empieza a entregarme un response 500 que creo que significa que no se obtuvo el dato.

cuando esta OK me entrega lo sgte:

```
response(2oo)
response(2oo)
response(2oo)
response(2oo)
response(2oo)
response(2oo)
response(5oo) <--- noe por que me arroja ese valor :( tampoco se que es, si 
                        pueden ayudarme.
response(2oo) 
response(2oo)
response(2oo)
response(2oo)
```

pero pasado un momento  me entrega el siguiente error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/pi/Desktop/newlas.py", line 23, in 
>   response = requests.get(url)  # response 200 = envio satisfactorio.
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
>   return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
>   return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in >request
>   resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
>   r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 473, in send
>   raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
>   requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', >ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
>
> ayuda amigos, tampoco logro ocupar un try catch, como pueden ver el en codigo, acabo de conocer python. y es amigable, solo que aun necesito aplicarlo a mi modelo..

Comment: Ese problema no es generado por el código que muestras, sino es la respuesta del servidor, los problemas de codigo 5xx indican que el servidor no esta disponible, revisa el servidor.

Comment: estoy haciendolo en modo local, con Mysql como base de datos, adicionalmente, recuerdo que en el desarrollo con un amigo, probamos con un mac lo mismo, y este no se paraba, pero eso si, en el caso de enviar el dato, en la URL la IP del  mac tenia al final lo siguiente
>8000  //supongo que era el puerto q utlizaba, en fin,la linea quedaba asi:

Comment: Una raspberry Pi no es lo mismo que una Mac, por lo que tiene limitaciones, si revisas el porcentaje de uso de la tarjeta obervaras que se sobrecarga, te recomiendo darle un pequeño sleep a tu bucle.

Comment: gracias, lo considerare, pero la mac no la uso del mismo modo que la raspberry,

envio datos desde 
>Raspberry Pi ----> Mac
>Raspberry Pi----->notebook normal. (solo que aca se corta la comunicacion)